# Need the result of os.system without printing terminal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, response

I am trying to wring code for IP ping monitor below code works well

```
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + "google.com")
        print(response)
        if response == 0:
            print("Google is up!")
        else:
            print("Google is down!")
```

Its gives the output like below

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.138/14.138/14.138/0.000 ms
0
Google is up!
```

But i need to suppress the console log. I need output like

```
Google is up!
```

`response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + "google.com"  >/dev/null 2>&1')` appending the " >/dev/null 2>&1" has hide the console log. But its return always some numerical value. So i got result like always down.

Comment: Look into the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Redirecting the output to `/dev/null` works for me and return 0 when success and non-0 in case of failure. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding, but isn't that first print(response) what is showing your undesired text?  Like I said...probably misunderstanding

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Yes I want the same. But in my case it's always return 1152.